# http get request in dart for imagga

Tags: python, flutter, dart

I am trying to make an API request using this code but it is in python. Would anyone know how to do this in dart/flutter? The code is:

```
api_key = '----'
api_secret = '----'
image_url = '----'

response = requests.get(
    '---' % image_url,
    auth=(api_key, api_secret))

print(response.json())
```

This code is supposed to call an http request to get information from the API, but fails in dart/flutter.

Answer (score 1):

To make an HTTP GET request in Dart, you can use the `http` package. Here's an example of how to make an HTTP GET request to the Imagga API in Dart:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() async {
  final apiKey = '<your_api_key_here>';
  final apiSecret = '<your_api_secret_here>';

  final imageUrl = '<your_image_url>';
  
  final authHeader = 'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('$apiKey:$apiSecret'));

  final apiUrl = 'https://api.imagga.com/v2/tags?image_url=$imageUrl';

  final response = await http.get(
       Uri.parse(apiUrl),
       headers: {'Authorization': authHeader}
  );

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final body = json.decode(response.body);
    print(body);
  } else {
    print('Request failed with status: ${response.statusCode}.');
  }
}
```

Comment: the http request requires authentication

Comment: I added basic auth to the answer